# Generators in category theory

Tags: category-theory

> An object K in a category C is called a generator if, for all pairs of
>   morphisms f, g : A → B between arbitrary objects A and B, f = g iff ∀e
>   : K → A. f ◦ e = g ◦ e.

Source: http://events.cs.bham.ac.uk/mgs2012/lectures/ReddyNotes.pdf (Page 7, Definition 3)

Can someone help me break down the meaning of this definition?

> for all pairs of morphisms `f, g : A → B`  between arbitrary types `A` and `B`

A morphism can be thought of as a a mapping from one type to another?

`f` and `g` are morphisms from type `A` to type `B`?

> f = g iff ∀e : K → A. ...

Morphism `f` is equivalent to morphism `g` if and only if for the morphism type `K` to type `A`

> f ◦ e = g ◦ e

`e` applied to `f` is equivalent to `e` applied to `g`

Is my interpretation of this correct?

The number of steps in this definition blows my mind, can anyone help me visualize the entire definition?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to math.stackexchange.

Comment: I am a developer and would like an answer in terms I can relate to, so I will leave this here for a while to see if anyone here can answer. Otherwise, I'll move it.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious intuition comes from the notion of *[well pointed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category)*. A well pointed category is simply a category $\cal C$ in which the final object $1$ exists and is a generator for $\cal C$. This means that for every $f,g:A \rightarrow B$,
$$ f = g \ \Leftrightarrow \forall p:1\rightarrow A, f\circ p = g\circ p$$

Note that $\circ$ is **composition** and not **application**! In haskell you would define:

```
f `comp` g = \x -> f (g x)
```

In programmatic notation the definition of well-pointedness gives

```
f == g iff for all p : () -> A, f `comp` p == g `comp` p
```

or unfolding the definitions

```
f == g iff for all p : () -> A, \x:() -> f (p x) == \x:() -> g (p x)
```

if we assume that the only inhabitant of `()` is in fact `()` (which is **not** the case in haskell, btw), then we get

```
f == g iff for all p : () -> A, \_ -> f (p ()) == \_ -> g (p ())
```

assuming extentionality (functions are equal if they are equal on all arguments)

```
f == g iff for all p, f (p ()) == g (p ())
```

Now the crucial observation, is that in "reasonable" categories, like $\mathrm{Set}$, morphisms $1\rightarrow A$ can be identified with *elements* of $A$ which gives

```
f == g iff for all x : A, f x == g x
```

which is obviously true in $\mathrm{Set}$ (this is exactly extentionality). Now note that "elements of an object of $\cal C$" doesn't even make *sense* in a general category, where objects are just "things" that can have morphisms into or out of them.

So the notion of well-pointedness says 2 things:

1. It's reasonable to treat morphisms $1\rightarrow A$ as "elements" of the object $A$
2. Extensionality holds.

It's reasonable to generalize this notion by replacing the terminal object $1$ by some arbitrary object $K$.

---

Now it might be useful to see a category where this **doesn't** hold (i.e. a category that is *not* well-pointed) just to see where this intuition can fail.

The simplest example I know of is the category of groups and group morphisms $\mathrm{Grp}$. Here the terminal (and initial) object $1$ is the group $\{e\}$ with a single element $e$, which is the unit for that group, and the operation $e*e=e$.

Because group morphisms *must* send $e$ to $e_G$ (the unit of $G$), there is always exactly 1 morphism $1\rightarrow G$ for any group $G$, namely, $\phi(e)=e_G$.

But now take any 2 distinct morphisms $f,g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, for example $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = 2\cdot n$.

It's **not** true that $f = g$ iff $\forall p : 1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, f\circ p = g\circ p$. Indeed there is only one $p$, namely $\phi$ from above, and $f\circ \phi(e) = g\circ \phi(e) = e_{\mathbb{Z}} = 0$. But $f \neq g$!

So $\mathrm{Grp}$ is not well-pointed, and it's not useful to treat morphisms $1\rightarrow G$ as points of $G$. However, in this case, there happens to be a generating object $K\neq 1$, so the generalization is useful after all! I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out what $K$ is...

---

I'll try to answer the questions more directly.

> A morphism can be thought of as a a mapping from one type to another?

Sort of. It's a good *intuition*, but you shouldn't think that it always makes sense to talk about *elements of type $A$*, unless you're working in a well-pointed category as explained above..

> Morphism `f` is equivalent to morphism `g` if and only if for the morphism type `K` to type `A`

It's *equal* rather than *equivalent* (though computer scientists tend to define equality in a much stricter sense than category theorists, e.g. by syntactic equality).

Also, it's "if and only if for **every** morphism from `K` to `A`", in general you can have many morphisms in `K -> A`

> `e` applied to `f` is equivalent to `e` applied to `g`

Composition (written $\circ$) is **not** application! I've tried to break it down above.

> The number of steps in this definition blows my mind, can anyone help me visualize the entire definition?

Category theory often offers very abstract definitions, and it's useful to work through examples and basic lemmas yourself to gain intuition.

However, if this helps, in the $\mathrm{Hask}$ category with types as objects and *total* programs of type `A -> B` as morphisms between `A` and `B`, **the unit type `()` is a generator**, as I tried to explain above.

Comment: I'm sure this is correct but it is way above my understanding. I'd be grateful if you could address the questions in my posting directly?

Comment: @BenAston Your ultimate question was, "can anyone help me visualize the entire definition?" That's arguably a very broad question, but it seems that's what cody has attempted to answer.